# Solution of Double Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the double integral over a rectangular region.
\begin{align*}
\int_{u=a}^{b}\int_{v=c}^{d}\sin(u^2-v^2)\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}u,
\end{align*}
where $a,b,c,d$ are any real constants.
I tried using substitution method, $u-v=x$ and $u+v=y$. I do not know how to solve further.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot go from $2$ variables to $1$ variable.

I suggest the substitution:

$$\begin{cases} u =\cosh(x)\\v = \sinh(y)\end{cases}$$

Don't forget about the jacobian!

Comment: what about limits? Sorry I didnt understand?